# Create New Form not reload after save

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

working good in **crm 2011** but not in **crm 2013 online**

On opportunity Entity create New record form i show only:

1.**Some attributes**(all other fields/Section/Tabs are hide on form)
2.and an **Html button** like

```js
function OnFormLoad(){   
  if(Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType() == 1 ) {

     SetRequiredLevelToNone();

     createHtmlButton("Save");

     HideTabsAndSections()    

  }
  else {    

  }
}
```

On click of **Html button** following function is triggered.

```js
function showWholeForm() {
  Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
}
```

I want to show all the fields of form after save, means want to reload whole form.
As working in crm 2011

Answer (score 0):

The `save` method in CRM 2013 will not refresh the page anymore. The new **`refresh`** method should be used in this case, as follows:

```
Xrm.Page.data.refresh(save).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

- ***save**: Boolean value to be passed as true if data should be saved
  after it is refreshed.*
- ***successCallback**: Function to call when the operation succeeds*
- ***errorCallbak**: Function to call when the operation fails, that will be passed an object with 2 properties - error code (number) and localized error message (string)*

You could find the method documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481607(v=crm.6).aspx

Comment: Accourding to sdk 2013 refresh method is only available for Updated Entities.

Comment: Definition of updated Entities:: All custom entities and certain system entities have an updated user interface that includes using the command bar and new form APIs. The updated system entities are listed in the following table:

Comment: I have try Xrm.Page.data.refresh(true/false) and also Xrm.Page.data.save().then(--,--) but my my field or not shown which i make them hide in create new record form by code  if(Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType() == 1 ){---}

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first disable the auto-save if you want **consistency** with **CRM 2011**.

```js
function OnSaveDisableAutoSave(eventArgs) {
   var saveType = eventArgs.getEventArgs().getSaveMode();
   if (saveType == 70 ||saveType  == 2)
   { //Disable AutoSave
      eventArgs.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

and then

```js
function showWholeForm() {
   Xrm.Page.data.refresh(true).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this not worked. I have tested in this way and again for confirmation i again test this one.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you can do:

```js
var saved = false;

function onLoad(){
    checkIfFormShouldBeReadOnly();
    attachEvent();
}

function attachEvent() {
    Xrm.Page.data.entity.addOnSave(executeOnSave);
}

function executeOnSave(saveExecution) {
    if (!saved) {
       saved = true;
       Xrm.Page.data.save().then(
          function () {
             checkIfFormShouldBeReadOnly();
          },
          function (errorCode, message) {
             Xrm.Page.data.refresh();
          }
       );
   }
}
```

Comment: I want to show all fields and section on form after creating the record. As i hide some fields and section during create of record. just like in 2011, after creating record whole form is reloaded with rendering whole form fields from begining without any code to show the fields and section which i hide during create.